# Entire view FPS drop when GMSMarker tracksViewChanges set to true

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

In Google Maps SDK for iOS, `tracksViewChanges` of `GMSMarker`, when set to `true`, likely caps FPS for other views in the entire view controller.

Some facts to start with:

- VC has a map with 5 `GMSMarkers`, and one collectionview with corresponding 5 cells
- Markers have custom iconView
- When scrolling collection view, cells in this collection AND markers are supposed to dynamically update their appearance (progressive animation directly tied to scroll event)

The scrolling animation, however, is choppy and anything but 60 FPS smooth.

You might say that's a performance reason but it's not the case, see:

- Xcode reports low memory usage and constant 60 FPS.
- Performance issues are 100% comparable on iPhone 5 through 7.
- When all views are removed (both from markers and collection view cells, having set only backgroundColor) and no animation methods are called, the scrolling still feels choppy, despite non-existent performance reasons for it.
- Same as with scroll, this affects some panning interactions as well, so its not exclusive to scrolling views.

Basically when all markers have `tracksViewChanges` set to `false`, I achieve heavenly animations. Even if I fake markers with custom UIViews, the FPS doesn't drop *at all*, even on old devices.

Now, if I set only ONE marker to have `tracksViewChanges` set to `true`, the FPS drop returns. Amount of markers that have enabled that parameter does not matter. I consider a FPS drop anything below 60 FPS, in this case, however, we're talking ~30 FPS.

Does this ring a bell?

Comment: Did you manage to find the cause for this problem? I'm having the same problem. When I change something on my iconView, I see the marker flashing rapidly between the changed version and unchanged version. Almost as if the GMSMarker is stuck in an endless redraw loop, slowing everything down.

Comment: @Flitskikker well, I did a workaround. I use markers and stuff only as referencing points and then render all the actual markers in a separate UIView (GM SDK provides methods to achieve this). Markers in the map are then static, which means, framerate from heaven :)

Comment: @dck can you post an example please?